# How do I pass plugin options in zweatherfeed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Plugin: http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zweatherfeed/

The plugin takes two parameters : a required array'location' and an optional 'options' (for which no type is defined).  For 'options' a list of 'plugin options' is given (please see link above).

I want to set the option of 'unit' to 'f' but passing the parameters as an object (as per normal in jquery?) is not working, nor is logging any errors in Firebug.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.site-description').weatherfeed({
        location : ['UKXX0085'],
        unit : 'f'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Zazar.net documentation](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zweatherfeed/), your own script only sets the location (for London, in this example). But yes, that is usually where you set all your options in jQuery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#test').weatherfeed(['UKXX0085']);
});
</script>
```

To set the other options for zWeather, you have to edit jquery.zweatherfeed.js directly. Note that I changed 'unit' to 'f' in the relevant part of the minified version.

```
(function(h){var j="odd";h.fn.weatherfeed=function(g,c)
{c=h.extend({unit:"f",image:!0,highlow:!0,wind:!0,link:!0,showerror:!0,linktarget:"_self"},c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is using the location as an option and not the first parameter.

For example, to configure parameters on zWeatherFeed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#test').weatherfeed(['UKXX0085','EGXX0011'], {
        unit: 'c',
        image: false,
        showerror: false
  });
});
</script>
```

http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zweatherfeed/